# Java does not recognise newline \n in log file on one computer

Tags: java, windows, javafx

I have this code for writing a log of outcomes into a txt file

```
aWriter.write(date + ";" + outcome + ";" + var2 + ";" + var + ";" + time + ";" + code + "\n");
```

When i open the log.txt file on my computer everything is as it's supposed to be, example:

```
> 2018-12-17;OK;456;456;14:0:9;123456
> 2018-12-17;OK;487;487;14:0:13L123456
> 2018-12-17;OK;456987;456987;14:0:20;123456
> 2018-12-18;NOK;3;123;8:51:12;123456
```

But, when i open this log file on a different computer that the program is running in i get this result:

```
2018-12-17;OK;456;456;14:0:9;1234562018-12-17;OK;487;487;14:0:13L1234562018-12-17;OK;456987;456987;14:0:20;1234562018-12-18;NOK;3;123;8:51:12;123456
```

What is the cause for this? is this My code or just some Windows default settings?

Comment: Are both systems windows?

Comment: Note that new line by default on Windows is CR/LF (`\r\n`). Try opening it with some non-basic tool, like Notepad++  .

Comment: Try open it with other editor (not notepad or word)

Comment: @Arnaud AFAIK *only* plain Notepad uses `\r\n` as newline. Every other tool can handle `\n` just fine. Simply avoid using Notepad and you fixed the problem (BTW: I really don't see the point of analysing logs using plain Notepad...)

Comment: Instead of using `\n`, use `System.lineSeparator()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every system uses the same line endings (and some text editor expect `\r\n` instead of `\n` since that's the platform-specific line separator for windows), you may use [`%n`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) using some sort of `Formatter`:

> 'n'   the platform-specific line separator as returned by
>   System.getProperty("line.separator").

Like this using `String#format`:

```
aWriter.write(
        String.format("%s%n", String.join(";", date, outcome, var2, var, time, code)));
//                       ^ %s prints the string, %n the line ending
```

Or more like your original code (without `%n`):

```
aWriter.write(String.join(";", date, outcome, var2, var, time, code) 
        + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

### Alternatively

You can configure what line endings your text editor will look for, this configuration is specific to your text editor of choice.

I've done a small test, if you want to keep using `Notepad` use the first solution, it will render files correctly if you use the correct line endings. Otherwise `Notepad++` will be able to read your file as is.

Comment: That won't help. The question is asking about *consuming* a file, not about producing one.

Comment: @IInspectable It's about "*writing a log of outcomes into a txt file*", right? And when opened in  a text editor it shows different results on different systems. I don't see that it's consuming it anywhere

Comment: Opening a file in a text editor is consuming it. Your proposed solution doesn't help. It merely changes, which text editors will render the file as desired and which ones won't. Had you address the core issue, this answer may have had value.

Comment: @IInspectable Fair enough I hadn't looked at it that way, I've updated the question with the core issue/alternative solution.

Comment: Hello, replacing \n with System.getProperty worked for me, Thank you